# Searching directories for exact matches, parent dirs, and subdirs

Tags: c++, file, search, directory

For a project I'm working on, I store a list of directories users enter to the program. When they enter a new directory, for my purposes I need to search the local list of added directories and determine weather the directory being searched for is

- An exact match of another entry
- A subdirectory of another entry
- A parent directory of another entry
- Not present in list

I have tried and tried, countless times to come up with a correct algorithm that does this, to no avail. This is the best I have gotten so far:

```
using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

vector<string>::const_iterator FindDir(const string &path, const vector<string> userRulePaths, const string &path, bool &parentDir, bool &existingSubdir, bool &validRule)
{
    bool exactRule = false;
    vector<string>::const_iterator foundRule;

    //returns true if 'needle' is a subdir of 'haystack'
    auto isSubDir = [&](const auto &needle, const auto &haystack)
    {
        fs::path needlePath(needle);
        const auto needleParentNum = distance(needlePath.begin(), needlePath.end()) - 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < needleParentNum; i++)
        {
            needlePath = move(needlePath.parent_path());
            if (needlePath.string() == haystack)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    };

    const auto exactSearchResult = lower_bound(userRulePaths.begin(), userRulePaths.end(), path);

    if (exactSearchResult != userRulePaths.end() && !(path < *exactSearchResult))
    {
        if (*exactSearchResult == path)
            exactRule = true;

        foundRule = exactSearchResult;
        validRule = true;
    }

    if (!exactRule)
    {
        const auto subDirSearchResult = lower_bound(userRulePaths.begin(), userRulePaths.end(), path,
            [&path](const string &str1, const string &str2) noexcept
            {
                if (auto cmp = strncmp(str1.data(), str2.data(), str1.size()))
                    return cmp < 0;

                return false;
            });

        if (subDirSearchResult != userRulePaths.end() && !(path < *subDirSearchResult))
        {
            if (*subDirSearchResult != path && isSubDir(path, *subDirSearchResult))
            {
                existingSubdir = true;
                foundRule = subDirSearchResult;
                validRule = true;
            }

            else if (*subDirSearchResult != path && isSubDir(*subDirSearchResult, path))
            {
                parentDir = true;
                foundRule = subDirSearchResult;
                validRule = true;
            }

            else if (*subDirSearchResult == path)
            {
                foundRule = subDirSearchResult;
                exactRule = true;
                validRule = true;
            }
        }

        else if (subDirSearchResult != userRulePaths.end() && isSubDir(*subDirSearchResult, path))
        {
            parentDir = true;
            foundRule = subDirSearchResult;
            validRule = true;
        }
    }

    return foundRule;
}
```

It works, but not all of the time. For example, given that I have "c:\users\root\downloads" and "c:\users\root\downloads\crystal disk mark", if I search for "c:\users\root\downloads", the function returns that it is an exact match. While that is true, in this case I need to know that "c:\users\root\downloads" is a parent directory of "c:\users\root\downloads\crystal disk mark". Other times subdirectories of existing files are not recognized as such or at all.

What changes are needed to make this algorithm correct? Or is there a totally different way of doing this that I'm missing?

Comment: Please give us examples. In which cases does your algorithm work and in which does it not work?

Comment: @Wum edited post to include example